# Covering both "www.domain.com" and "domain.com" in config file settings

Tags: config, multi-environment

How can I cover both "www.domain.com" and "domain.com" with the same settings in my config file? My current file is set up like this:

```
return array(
    '*' => array(
       // Settings here
    ),

    // Local
    'domain.dev' => array(
       // Settings here
    ),

    // Staging
    'staging.domain.com' => array(
        // Settings here
    ),

    // Production
    'www.domain.com' => array(
       // Settings here
    )
);
```

Can I just remove the `www` from the last entry under “Production” to have those settings apply to both the naked domain and the `www` subdomain?

And if I'm including the `www` in my `siteUrl` config setting in Production, will that create any conflicts if visitors end up at a naked url without the `www` subdomain specified?

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What I like to do is explicitly set `CRAFT_ENVIRONMENT` in my index.php:

```
switch($_SERVER['SERVER_NAME']) {
  case 'domain.dev':
    define('CRAFT_ENVIRONMENT', 'LOCAL');
    break;
  case 'staging.domain.com':
    define('CRAFT_ENVIRONMENT', 'STAGING');
    break;
  case 'www.domain.com':
  case 'domain.com':
    define('CRAFT_ENVIRONMENT', 'PRODUCTION');
    break;
}
```

Then in the config file:

```
return array(
  '*' => array(
    // Settings here
  ),
  'LOCAL' => array(
    // Settings here
  ),
  'STAGING' => array(
    // Settings here
  ),
  'PRODUCTION' => array(
    // Settings here
  )
);
```

When you set `CRAFT_ENVIRONMENT` you may want to use the switch default for `LOCAL` or for `PRODUCTION` - there are good arguments for going either way.

A separate question is whether you *should* have people accessing your site at both `www.domain.com` and `domain.com`. The answer is most probably **no**. Pick one, and use .htaccess (on apache) or whatever other method, to redirect either all the www to non-www or the other way around. Otherwise you will have duplicate content, which confuses the search engines (and generally looks unprofessional).

Comment: Thanks for the tip Marion. If I wanted to use the switch default for `PRODUCTION` would I write it like this:

`default:
    define('CRAFT_ENVIRONMENT', 'PRODUCTION');
    break;
}`
?

Comment: Sorry for the nonexistent multi-line formatting. Hope you can make sense of that.

Comment: yes, exactly...